# Unhandled exception type NoSuchFieldException (java reflection)

Tags: java, reflection, playframework

I am using Play Framework about 1 month and it is a great thing, but I had one big problem
.
I`ve try to run following code in secure controller:

```
MyModel myModel = MyModel.all().first(); 
Field idField = myModel.getClass().getField("id");
```

About line 2 Play says: 
Compilation error

```
The file /app/controllers/Security.java could not be compiled. Error 
raised is : Unhandled exception type NoSuchFieldException
```

Maybe it`s a core bug? 
Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should handle the exception that getField(String fieldName) can throw. In this case a NoSuchFieldException.

Try to write it as such:

```
Field idField = null;
try {
    idField = myModel.getClass().getField("id");
} catch (NoSuchFieldException nsfe) {
    throw new RuntimeException(nsfe);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you use [dp4j](http://dp4j.com)'s `@TestPrivates` or `@Reflect(catchExceptions =true)` you don't need to write the catch statements yourself:

```
public class Security{

@Reflect(catchExceptions =true) //when false it will add the exceptions to the throws list.
public void aMethod(){
    MyModel myModel = MyModel.all().first(); 
    Field idField = myModel.getClass().getField("id"); 
    //you might as well write:
    // int id = myModel.id;
}
```